# Is it possible to concatenate string with job parameter in pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Pipeline jenkins job with a checkout step that I want to modify to accept the branch as a parameter.

Currently, this is how we checkout:

```
stage('Prepare'){
        steps {
               checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', "..." remote: 'http://svn.xxx.bbb/svn/yyy/branches/version_2017']]])
        }
}
```

I would like to change the checkout to something like :

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', "..." remote: 'http://svn.xxx.bbb/svn/yyy/params.BRANCH/params.VERSION']]])
```

Anyone has done something similar? I can't figure out if it is possible to concatenate a string with job parameters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The thing you're missing is Groovy's [String Interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation): Inside double-quoted strings, `${..}` allows you to include groovy code:

```java
def test = 'world'
println "hello ${test}" // prints hello world
println 'hello ${test}' // prints hello ${test}
```

So in your example, use

```java
remote: "http://svn.xxx.bbb/svn/yyy/${params.BRANCH}/${params.VERSION}"
```